# Deploy .json file with UserControl WinForms

Tags: c#, user-controls

I have built a custom User Control in Visual Studio (Win Forms).

This User Control requires a .json file to be deployed along with it.

Short Version: How is this possible?

Long Version:
When I am testing the User Control from with the Control designer itself, it works no problem.
This would be because I have set the following:

Build Action to Content and;
Copy To Output Directory - Copy if Newer

So when I'm debugging it, everything is there, as I expect it to be.

The problem occurs when I create a separate Win Forms application, and add this newly designed control to the Palette by:

Right click Toolbox->Choose Items->Browse->Browse to the Project Directory of the Control->Select the DLL->OK

It show up on my Palette, but the problem is of course when I drop the User Control onto the form itself. It has no means of getting "MyFile.json" from User Control Application/Dll to the Current Project.

How do I make this work?

Chud

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to build your json file as a `EmbeddedResource` instead of `Content`. That way it will be embedded into the UserControl's binary (the dll file itself). You can then use `ResourceManager` class to read it in your code.

If you're going to change the content of json file at runtime, you can instead create an application setting of `string` type that stores the actual json content. This setting can then be read/written easily using `ProjectName.Properties.Settings.Default.YourSettingName`.

Also note that if you have set your json file's Build Action to `Content` and `Copy to Output Directory` to `Always Copy`, and you add a reference to this project from another project **that also exists in that solution**, the content file (json file) should get copied to the bin folder correctly. But if your UserControl project does not exist in the current solution, or you're referencing your control through **Browse** button, you'll not get your content files. This may not seem obvious, but once you think about it, you'll understand that VS cannot figure out what dependencies does a DLL file has if you simply add a file reference.

In the latter case, a setting is the cheapest solution (described above) that you can use.

Comment: OK - I just tried that and the same thing applies. I get my custom msg of "File Does Not Exist" when I Drop the Control.

Comment: To your edit - Yes - I will be changing the content, based on user selection. It might be say empty on deploy, and altered by user. However, I would like the UserControl to handle the creation/deployment of the file itself

Comment: An application setting should work perfectly fine for this scenario. Do you have any issue with that?